# C++ error C2664 with CStrings

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have some old C++ file which I know used to compile. I have created a new install of Visual C++ version 6.

I am getting lots of compile errors with CStrings about not being able to convert to const char *

Here's an example.

```
CString dogs = "test";
writeoutfile(dogs, 1);

void Crender::writeoutfile(CString data, long data_size) {}
```

I get this error:

> error C2664: 'void __thiscall Crender::writeoutfile(const char *,long)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'class CString' to 'const char *'

Is there some way I can get round this?

Comment: Either the prototype of `writeoutfile` does not match the implementation you have there (it expects a `const char *`, not a `CString`), or you have typedeffed `CString` to `const char *` somewhere.

Comment: Quite rightI  I had changed the cpp file but not the h file. It used to say void writeoutfile (LPCSTR data, long data_size = -1). I changed the first argument to CString only to try and simplify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the raw pointer to the char field. This can be done with

```
CString::GetBuffer()
```

so you could call

```
writeoutfile(dogs.GetBuffer(), 1);
```

Comment: Note that this discards any encoding information and may result in unreadable data.

Comment: GetBuffer requires a min length argument. What should this be? It also returns the wrong type.

Answer (score 0):

CString should convert to const char*. Is it a Unicode build? That's the only explanation I can think of.

GetBuffer() is for getting a writeable pointer to the data contained inside CString. Don't do that!